# Can't get multiview control to change views

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, multiview

I have a multiview control, that has two views. View1 is the default view, and View2 is the new view. When the end user click a button, I want to change the view to View2. I can't seem to achieve this anyway I go.

ASP.NET Code:

```
<asp:MultiView ID="MVOrder" runat="server">
    <asp:View ID="VOrderNow" runat="server">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="LblInfo" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        &nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="LblDrink" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="LblItemInfo" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        &nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <br />
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </asp:View>
    <asp:View runat="server" ID="VOrderComplete">

    <table class="auto-style1">
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
            <asp:Label ID="LblOrderComplete" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
            <asp:Label ID="LblOrderNumberAgain" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
            <asp:Label ID="LblOrderTimeAgain" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    </asp:View>
<br/>
</asp:MultiView>
```

Button Click Event Code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //MVOrder.ActiveViewIndex = 1;
            MVOrder.SetActiveView(VOrderComplete);
        }
```

Page Load Code:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    MVOrder.SetActiveView(VOrderNow);
}
```

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: are you getting any errors?

Comment: @ethorn10 Nope, no errors. It look like the page refreshes, but the view doesn't change

Comment: I am pretty sure with the way you have this structured, you won't be able to do what you want. The `UpdatePanel` is doing an async call and thus any UI update will be on itself and not the `View` or `MultiView`.

Comment: @ethorn10 Okay. Well how can I use my update panel(because I need it to update controls), and the multiview @ the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might have some additional code that might make this not work properly. But based on what you've shown, this will post and update your view:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:MultiView ID="MVOrder" runat="server">
            <asp:View ID="VOrderNow" runat="server">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><asp:Label ID="LblInfo" runat="server" Text="asdfasdfasdf"></asp:Label></td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><asp:Label ID="LblDrink" runat="server" Text="lmnoplmnop"></asp:Label></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><asp:Label ID="LblItemInfo" runat="server" Text="iteminfo"></asp:Label></td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <br />
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
            </asp:View>
            <asp:View runat="server" ID="VOrderComplete">
                <table class="auto-style1">
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td><asp:Label ID="LblOrderComplete" runat="server" Text="ordercomplete"></asp:Label></td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td><asp:Label ID="LblOrderNumberAgain" runat="server" Text="ordernumberagain"></asp:Label></td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td><asp:Label ID="LblOrderTimeAgain" runat="server" Text="ordertimeagain"></asp:Label></td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </asp:View>
            <br />
        </asp:MultiView>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```