# Jquery to function in ASP

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a script that is loaded into my page. In this script I would like when it finishes what it has to do it changes a multiview active index property. In other words, when the script finishes, the multiview shows a different view.

I've been searching and so far it looks like I would have to implement AJAX, my question is, is there an easy way to do this without AJAX? Is there a way of telling my Jquery to execute a function (not a webmethod) in my page.cs.aspx?

Comment: you question is about asp or aspx page ?

Comment: Ajax exists as a simple solution to this type of problem. Rather than try and avoid it, which typically requires even more work, *try to use it*. It is not that difficult to use :)

Answer (score 1):

> is there an easy way to do this without AJAX? Is there a way of
>   telling my Jquery to execute a function (not a webmethod) in my
>   page.cs.aspx

Well ,Sort of. You are at the  Client side.

So - "Without `Ajax`  /  without `Webmethod`" — it would leave you with  *three* options which are  : `WebSockets`  ,  `server sent events` and `Changed Iframe source`.

Please notice that you will need supporting software on the server side in order to allow this. And also that SSE are [not supported in all browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=eventsource).

Comment: Fast and cruel... ='(

Comment: jQuery runs on the client.  In order to perform a server side action, you need to make a request to the server, hence AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to call server-side functions without ajax, or more complicated things like sockets - as @royi-namir stated.

A possible solution if you are looking to avoid ajax, etc.:
If you do not have a lot of server-side functionality in your MultiView (just text/control rendering or something not affected by your script), you could get rid of the MultiView and just load whatever is necessary initially, and have it hidden.  Then add, to the end of your script, a js call to show the content of your view (probably just a div or something now.)

OR
use an UpdatePanel, and let that do the ajax for you and render that part of the page again with the correct multiview view. [a way to use multiview with update panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27576631/cant-get-multiview-control-to-change-views) I don't prefer these types of ajax, because they can introduce more problems than they solve if you are unfamiliar with them.  Here you would just have your script do something to trigger the update panel to update.  You could register something explicit from the server to the script manager, or do something a little jenky and click a button **inside the update panel** that would cause a postback, or something along those lines.